# Creating for loop, df to ascii with x y z

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, ascii

I have a dataframe:

[image]

In total more than 3 million rows and 1800 species (scientific name)

The code below creates an empty raster at 0.5 degree scale..

```
library(raster)
ext <- extent(-180.0, 180, -90.0, 90.0)
gridsize <- 0.5
tempraster<- raster(ext, res=gridsize)
crs(tempraster) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"`
```

#and then the code below fills that raster with x y data one species at a time, creating an ascii as per the scientific name, with a 1 where the species is and a 0 where it is not.

```
selection<-animals
spp <- unique(animals$scientific_name)
result <- list()
for (i in 1:length(spp)) {
  spi <- selection[selection$scientific_name == spp[i], c("lon", "lat")]      
  fname <- paste0(spp[i], ".asc")
  result[[i]] <- rasterize(spi, tempraster, fun="count", filename=fname, background = 0, overwrite = TRUE)}
```

I would like to adjust this code so that instead of the resulting ascii having a 1 where the species is, it uses the value from the total column. Unfortunately I am a beginner at for loops and other functions so am asking for any help.

Comment: what do you mean by ascii here? [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)? Not sure if the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ascii) you applied is relevant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rasterize()` function has `field` argument, so you can call it like this:

```
result[[i]] <- rasterize(spi, tempraster, 
                         field=selection[selection$scientific_name == spp[i], "total"], 
                         fun=sum,
                         filename=fname, background = 0, 
                         overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: That is exactly it, I knew I could use a different function, e.g. rasterize, but didn't know how to edit it into the existing code - thank you!

Comment: glad if it helped. If your question is solved, feel free to [mark it as such](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Also, maybe consider changing the title of your question - I think it is not really about `for` loop, rather about use of `rasterize()`.

Comment: Also, note that I removed the `fun=count` part from your code. With it, rasterize would be placing number of occurrences in the cell. When `fun` is not defined, `rasterize()` uses the `last()` function - which I think is also not correct in your usecase, you should rather use `fun=sum`. I have now added it to my answer.